# Improving background subtraction when encountering split objects in foreground masks

Tags: python, opencv

For a project I implemented a simple background subtraction using a median background estimation. The result is not bad, but often moving objects (people in my test examples) are cut in unconnected blobs.

I tried calling open and close operations (I removed the close operation, because it seemed as if it wouldn't improve the result) on the foreground mask to improve the result, which worked to some degree. However, I am wondering if there are even more ways how I could improve the foreground mask. It is still a fair bit away from the ground truth.

I am aware that playing around with the threshold itself is also always a viable solution and I do play around with that too. That being said, I focus on reducing noise to a minimum. I also tried adaptive thresholding, but that didn't look very promising for this usecase.

Without opening:

[image]

With opening:
[image]

I am more looking for general approaches than to actual implementations.

**Pseudocode of background subtraction**

1. Greyscale all images.
2. Make a background estimation by calculating the median for every r,g and b value for every pixel in a subset of all images.
3. Then take every image and calculate the absolute difference between that image and the background estimation.
4. Apply a threshold to get a binary result called the foreground mask
5. Use opencvs open operation once.

Comment: It would help to see the original images you are trying to compare and your code.

Comment: Sadly I can't publish them due to legal reasons. I make the idea of the code more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the greyscale simplification.
Simple is good.
We should make everything as simple as
possible, but not simpler.

Let's attack your model for a moment.
An evil clothing designer with an army
of fashion models sends them walking
past your camera, each wearing a red
shirt that is slightly darker than
the preceding one.
At least **one** of the models will be
"invisible" against some of your background pixels,
having worn a matching shade,
with matching illumination,
compared with the median pixel value.
Repeat with a group of green shirts, then blue.

How to remedy this?
In each channel compute the median red,
median green, median blue pixel intensity.
At inference time, compute three absolute
value differences.
Threshold on max of those deltas.

---

Computing over sensor R, G, B is straightforward.
Human perception more closely aligns with H, S, V.
Consider computing max delta over those three,
or over all six.

---

For each background pixel,
compute both expected value and variance,
either for the whole video or for one-minute
slots of time.
Now, at inference time, the variance
informs your thresholding decision,
improving its accuracy.

For example, some pixels may have constant
illumination, others slowly change with the
movement of the sun, and others are quite
noisy when wind disturbs the leaves of
vegetation. The variance lets you capture
this quite naturally.

---

For a *much* more powerful modeling approach,
go with Optical Flow.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html